# How To Delete S3 Files Starting With

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto

Let's say I have images of different sizes on S3:

```
137ff24f-02c9-4656-9d77-5e761d76a273.webp
137ff24f-02c9-4656-9d77-5e761d76a273_500_300.webp
137ff24f-02c9-4656-9d77-5e761d76a273_400_280.webp
```

I am using boto to delete a single file:

```
bucket = get_s3_bucket()
s3_key = Key(bucket)
s3_key.key = '137ff24f-02c9-4656-9d77-5e761d76a273.webp'
bucket.delete_key(s3_key)
```

But I would like to delete all keys starting with 137ff24f-02c9-4656-9d77-5e761d76a273.

Keep in mind there might be hundreds of files in the bucket so I don't want to iterate over all files. Is there a way to delete only files starting with certain string?

Maybe some regex delete function.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The S3 service does support a multi-delete operation allowing you to delete up to 1000 objects in a single API call.  However, this API call doesn't provide support for server-side filtering of the keys.  You have to provide the list of keys you want to delete.

You could roll your own.  First, you would want to get a list of all the keys you want to delete.

```
import boto

s3 = boto.connect_s3()
bucket = s3.get_bucket('mybucket')
to_delete = list(bucket.list(prefix='137ff24f-02c9-4656-9d77-5e761d76a273'))
```

The `list` call returns a generator but I'm converting that to a list using `list` so, the `to_delete` variable now points to list of all of the objects in the bucket that match the prefix I have provided.

Now, we need to create chunks of up to 1000 objects from the big list and use the chunk to call the `delete_keys` method of the bucket object.

```
for chunk in [to_delete[i:i+1000] for i in range(0, len(to_delete), 1000)]:
    result = bucket.delete_keys(chunk)
    if result.errors:
        print('The following errors occurred')
        for error in result.errors:
            print(error)
```

There are more efficient ways to do this (e.g. without converting the bucket generator into a list) and you probably want to do something different when handling the errors but this should give you a start.

Answer (score 9):

you can do it using aws cli : https://aws.amazon.com/cli/ and some unix command.

**this aws cli commands should work:**

```
aws s3 rm <your_bucket_name> --exclude "*" --include "*137ff24f-02c9-4656-9d77-5e761d76a273*"
```

if you want to include sub-folders you should add the flag **--recursive**

**or with unix commands:**

```
aws s3 ls s3://<your_bucket_name>/ | awk '{print $4}' | xargs -I%  <your_os_shell>   -c 'aws s3 rm s3:// <your_bucket_name>  /% $1'
```

explanation:
list all files on the bucket **--pipe-->** 
get the 4th parameter(its the file name) **--pipe-->**
run delete script with aws cli

Comment: For those landing here to delete objects with a key, considerable frustration may be avoided by noting that if there is an object key trailing the bucket name, the form `aws s3 rm s3://mybucket/mykey/ --exclude "*" --include "*mypattern" --recursive` is the incantation.

Answer (score 6):

Yes. try using`s3cmd`, command line tool for S3. First get the list of all files in the bucket.

```
cmd = 's3cmd ls s3://bucket_name'
args = shlex.split(cmd)
ls_lines = subprocess.check_output(args).splitlines()
```

Then find all lines that start with your desired string(using regex, should be simple). The delete all of thrm using the command:

```
s3cmd del s3://bucket_name/file_name(s)
```

Or if you just wanna use a single command:

```
s3cmd del s3://bucket_name/string*
```

I mentioned the first method so that you can test the names of files you are deleting and don't accidently delete anything else.

Comment: That wildcard-delete using asterix (*) definitely works `s3://bucket-name/string*`!!!!!!!!

Comment: However it seems that under the hood `s3cmd` will delete files one by one (taking in my case approx 0.5sec per file). So if you need to delete half a million files very quickly, then you will need solutions based on multi-delete. But for occasional cleaning of S3 bucket this method seems perfectly fine

Answer (score 4):

For boto3 the following snippet removes all files starting with a particular prefix:

```
import boto3

botoSession = boto3.Session(
    aws_access_key_id     = <your access key>,
    aws_secret_access_key = <your secret key>,
    region_name           = <your region>,
)

s3 = botoSession.resource('s3')
bucket = s3.Bucket(bucketname)
objects = bucket.objects.filter(Prefix=<your prefix>)
objects.delete()
```

Answer (score 1):

While there's no direct boto method to do what you want, you should be able to do it efficiently by using [`get_all_keys`](http://boto.readthedocs.org/en/latest/ref/s3.html#boto.s3.bucket.Bucket.get_all_keys), filtering them with the said regex, and then calling [`delete_keys`](http://boto.readthedocs.org/en/latest/ref/s3.html#boto.s3.bucket.Bucket.delete_keys).

Doing it this way will use only two requests, and doing the regex client-side should be pretty fast